# Why AddGantt or AddGanttColor returns the same index for different invocations?

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-5

For some reason for certain cases when adding gantts to a TGanttSeries instance using method AddGanttColor or AddGantt the same index is returned for two different calls.

For example, the following snippet illustrates the case where the last two calls both return index of value 1.

```
Series.AddGanttColor(0, 100, 0, 'WA #234', clGreen);   // returns value 0
Series.AddGanttColor(100, 200, 1, 'WA #235', clGreen); // returns value 1 
Series.AddGanttColor(50, 200, 2, 'WA #237', clGreen);  // returns value 1!
```

However, all three gantts are displayed. So, it seems that the third line added gantt as the second in the list, and moved the gantt added on the second line to be the last one (third, and having index 2).

Could anyone please explain how could this be remedied to ensure that returned indexes stay associated with gantts as per AddGanttColor calls. In the above example, I would expect index values 0, 1, and 2 to be associated with the first, second and third added gantt respectively.

---

Have just confirmed that this situation holds true for TeeChart versions 5 and 8 running under Delphi 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... after some research the cause of the problem was narrowed down to the value of property `Series.XValues.Order`. This property should be set to `loNone` in order to preserve association between index values returned from AddGantt and corresponding gantts.

IMO this is an API deficiency.

Comment: This is because most series styles are designed to plot sequential data. If that's not the case you can easily change that.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet It took me awhile to figure this out. By default TGanttSeries has XValues.Order set to loAscending. By "sequential" I personally would expect the order in which gantts are added. Otherwise  the returned from AddXXX methods index values are really misleading and error prone.